# Dividing with imaginary numbers, simplifying

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, divisibility, real-numbers

Alright, so I have $8-\frac{6i}{3i}$.

I multiplied by the conjugate of $3i$, and got $-18-\frac{24i}{9}$.

This is the part that confuses me, because I don't know how to divide this. Can I divide the $-18$ by $9$, which gives me $-2$, and then add that to $\frac{-8i}{3}$? That would make my final answer $(2) + \left(\frac{-8i}{3} \right)$.

Or would I have to divide everything by the greatest common factor, which is 3, and in that case my final answer would be $-6- \frac{8i}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that parenthesis are missing. Otherwise this question wouldn't make any sense. Step by step solution is 
$$\frac{8-6i}{3i}=\frac{i(8-6i)}{3i^2}=\frac{8i+6}{-3}=-2-\frac{8}{3}i.$$

Comment: Although you answered my question, I'm not sure what you did in step two. Shouldn't you have multiplied by the conjugate of 3i, which is -3i?

Comment: @johny Do you know the reason behind multiplying by the complex conjugate?